# How do I remove the warning: Control reaches end of non-void function?

Tags: c, gcc

I know it's caused by the absence of return at the end of the function, but what if i only want it to return under a specific condition. I tried to transfer the return in the of the function, but it returns the first dim it sees which i do not want to happen.

```
char dimension(void)
{
    char dim,d;
    printf("2D or 3D?\n");
    dim=getchar();
    if(dim=='2'||dim=='3')
    {
        d=getchar();
        if(d=='\n')
        {
            printf("You selected %cD\n",dim);
            return dim;
        }
        else
        {
            for(;d!='\n';d=getchar());
            if(d=='\n')
            dimension();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(;d!='\n';d=getchar());
        if(d=='\n')
        dimension();
    }   
//return dim; --> undesired return value.

}
```

Comment: But what if this condition isn't met??

Comment: I want it to keep repeating the function (recursive) can it work like that?

Comment: you're calling the function recursively, but if the lowest level returns something, it's value is ignored up the upper levels, so no - it doesn't work like that

Comment: @helpme, in your code you have the `else` that runs `d=getchar()`, and after that the execution has to stop, and the function - to return something.

Comment: So to avoid that, how come i cant just put the return value in the upper level and not put any return value at the end?

Comment: @ForceBru I tried to remove the else. It still has the same warning.

Comment: Trace through ALL possible paths through your function.  If they all return a value, you will not get the warning:)

Comment: @helpme, now in the upper-level `else`, what if `d` is not equal to the newline character?

Comment: @ForceBru It should go to else which recurses the function. Thats how i understood it..Is that right?

Comment: Who knows?  We have no idea what your function is supposed to do, or how the callers might need error indications.  Maybe you can return NUL for an error, maybe not.  Maybe you need to return a success/fail boolean and use indirection to return the char.  Maybe return an error number.  YOU designed it!

Comment: @helpme, in the `else` that is at the bottom of your code, you recurse only if `d == '\n'` is true. Otherwise you must return something, but you don't. The same applies to the `else` that is one level deeper.

Comment: You have specified a return type for the function.  So in valid input, you return your result.  In the case of an error you will need to return a value which represents a value identified as an error.  I suggest you rewrite your function so it has a return value which specifies if the function worked or not.  0 being it worked, non zero being an error.  The existing output be moved to a function parameter passed by reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program seems more complex than it needs to be, and the problems seem to center around disposal of the trailing newline.

Better to write a function dedicated to clearing the input stream. Also note that `getchar()` returns `EOF` in the event of an error, or if the user signals `EOF` from the keyboard, or potentially if input has been redirected from a file. The `clear_stdin()` function below checks for both `\n` and `EOF` to avoid an infinite loop in such a case.

As pointed out by [@IanAbbott](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141334/how-do-i-remove-the-warning-control-reaches-end-of-non-void-function/43142027#comment73362363_43142027), `dim` should be an `int`, since the return type of `getchar()` is `int`, and a `char` may not hold the value of `EOF`. If there were and error in `getchar()`, an infinite recursion would be entered unless `dimension()` explicitly checks for `EOF`. I have added code that prints an error message and returns `'?'` if `dim` is `EOF`. The calling function can handle the error by checking for `'?'`; the program could instead `exit()` when an error is detected.

Also note that a function that is declared with a return value *must* return a value. Here, if the user's input is acceptable it is returned, otherwise the result of calling `dimension()` again is returned.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char dimension(void);
void clear_stdin(void);

int main(void)
{
    char c = dimension();

    printf("%c returned from dimension()\n", c);

    return 0;
}

char dimension(void)
{
    int dim;

    printf("2D or 3D?\n");
    dim = getchar();

    if (dim == EOF) {
        printf("Error or EOF in getchar()\n");
        return '?';
    }

    if (dim == '2' || dim == '3') {
        int c;
        if ((c = getchar()) == '\n' || c == EOF) {
            printf("You selected %cD\n",dim);
            return dim;
        }
    }

    clear_stdin();

    puts("Invalid selection");        
    return dimension();
}

void clear_stdin(void)
{
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Sample interaction

```
2D or 3D?
1 
Invalid selection
2D or 3D?
23
Invalid selection
2D or 3D?
4
Invalid selection
2D or 3D?
3
You selected 3D
3 returned from dimension()
```

Comment: In `dimension()`, `dim` should be an `int` to hold the result of `getchar()`.

Comment: @IanAbbott-- I considered changing OP's code to use `int` instead of `char`, but decided against it. I did intend to mention the issue, and forgot. But now that I look again, I see that an error in `getchar()` could lead to an infinite recursion. I will update. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: /*if(dim == '2' || dim == '3')
    {
    d=getchar();
    if(d=='\n')
    {
         printf("You selected %cD\n",dim);
         return dim;
    }
    clear_stdin();
    printf("Invalid Selection\n");
    return dimension(); 
    }*/->i  did this instead to distinguish inputs that start with 2 and 3(ex. 2343 and 345) from inputs "2" and"3"

Comment: @helpme-- I have updated the code in my answer to ignore inputs such as "234". Your fundamental problem could have been solved by using `return dimension()` in place of `dimension()` in the original code, and by changing the commented-out final statement from `return dim` to `return dimension()`. Still, code was needlessly complex, and the checks for `EOF` are needed for robust code.

Comment: @DavidBowling Thank you so much. The extra function really simplified my other functions as well. I see how separating it to functions can make it easier.

Comment: @helpme-- One thing to remember about functions like `clear_stdin()` is that they expect there to be characters in the input stream. If you call `clear_stdin()` with an input stream that is already empty, it will block and wait for more user input.

Comment: @DavidBowling hmm that makes sense. Thank you!